# How to use $(this).text() as Id selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I extracted text from table `<p>` tag and then I want to use it as id selector.

So I tried `$('#'+$(this).text())` but it didn't work. I checked that `$('#'+'string')` is working but I don't know why that is not working..

this is my jquery code

```
$("#chosen").on("click", "tr td:not(:last-child)", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var col3 = tr.find("td:eq(3)").find('P');
    $(col3).each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
        var data = $('#'+$(this).text()).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $('#'+$(this).text()).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
    var col4 = tr.find("td:eq(4)").find('P');

});
```

And this is table that I extract text:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="thead-light border">
            <th>name</th>
            <th>difficulty</th>
            <th>goal</th>
            <th>recommended</th>
            <th>return</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="chosen">
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
                <p>recommended2</p>
                <p>recommended3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

++)Sorry, I forgot to post codes that has id

```
<map name="image-map">
    <area id="recommended1" target="" alt="1" title="헤이븐" coords="118,392,9" shape="circle">
    <area id="recommended2" target="" alt="2" title="기계무덤 : 기계무덤 입구" coords="68,415,4" shape="circle">
                // I skipped almost for readability. 
</map>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any elements with an `id` attribute that would match any of the text.

Comment: How would, for example, `헤이븐` be expect to match up with, also for example, `recommended1`?

Comment: @Ouroborus oh..I made a mistake by reducing the code to make it easier to understand. in this case, id should be "recommended1".. I'm so sorry

Comment: I suspect `$('#'+$(this).text())` is working fine and it's what you are doing with its results that is the problem. You might try `console.log($('#'+$(this).text())).length)` and check the debugging console to see if it returns `1` which would mean it did grab an element.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? And you don't have any `data-*` attributes so calling `.data('maphilight')` won't do anything.

Comment: @Jasen That depends. If you're strictly setting the data by using `.data()`, it doesn't show up as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $(col3).each(function() {
```

to

```
col3.each(function() {
```

the col3 var is already a array of elements

Comment: I don't know that that fixes anything. When you try to wrap a jQuery object, you just end up with a copy of that object.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm not sure that fixes the whole problem idd, But fixing every problem starts by fixing mistakes in the code.